# How to switch user in gnome shell?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, switch-user

I am using gnome-shell on Ubuntu 12.04.  On the guest account, I have this handy option switch user, but when I am logged into my own account it is not there for some reason.

Why isn't it there anymore, and how can I get it back?  At the moment I can use the workaround to lock screen and I get a switch user button from there, but it would be nicer to have the menu option as I was used to.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you install any extensions?

Comment: Creepy eye, dude.

Comment: I think ubuntu doesn't show _Switch user_ option when there are no any other User accounts other than _guest_ ....

Comment: @ Parasd --- You are wrong Switch user option is always shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there for me in 12.04. I didn't have to do anything to get it other than have other userid's set up.

Here's a screenshot of it:

[image]

I think Anwar's question in his comment above is insightful. Have you installed any extensions? If so you may wish to remove them, reboot, and see if there is still a problem. If the problem goes away you can add them again one-by-one to see which one interferes.

After selecting `Switch User` I'm sent back to the Ubuntu login screen (lightdm) where I can choose another userid, enter a password, and select the kind of session I want to start. I was able to start another session that way (on virtual tty 9 in my case) and switch back forth with Alt-Ctrl-F7 and Alt-Ctrl-F9.

Comment: thanks, i don't have any extensions but it came back on its own!  i have no idea why or how.  i'm accepting your answer so that my question doesn't show up in unanswered searches.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome 3 displays the `Switch User` option only when you have multiple [normal user accounts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html#s8.1.1) on your system with a user id between 1000 and 29999 (Debian, Ubuntu).

If you want to switch to a user account within the [reserved id range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Reserved_ranges) of your distribution, you can lock the screen with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and click on `Log in as another user` below the login form.